# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error - JSP - Glass Fish server

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, glassfish

As a beginner to Jsp and Java , I'm building a simple web application that displays data from data base to web page

When i run the below code i'm getting the following error **HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error**

Building web application in net beans and web server is Glass fish

Don't know what went wrong .Still searching Google but no luck yet

```
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Update1:**

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.nextPage_jsp._jspService(nextPage_jsp.java:111)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Index.jsp**

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Jan 1, 2015, 7:36:04 PM
    Author     : ksathis
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Inside</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Inside</h1>
        <form name="mainForm" action="nextPage.jsp" method="POST">
            <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>DateRange</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="radioS" id="dateRadio" value="1" /></td>
                        <td><input type="date" name="date1" value="0" size="10" /></td>
                        <td><input type="date" name="date2" value="0" size="10" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>WeekNum</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="radioS" id="weekRadio" value="1" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="weeknum1" id="weeknum1" value="0" size="10" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>MonthNum</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="radioS"  id="monthRadio" value="1" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="monthnum1" value="0" size="10" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Clear" size="10"/><input type="submit" value="submit" name="Clear" size="10"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Nextpage.jsp**

```
<%-- 
    Document   : nextPage
    Created on : Jan 1, 2015, 7:55:59 PM
    Author     : ksathis
--%>

<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>DIS SLA RESULT FOR THE WEEK !</h1>
        <%!
            public class imaging {

                String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database1";
                String USERNAME = "root";
                String PASSWORD = "password";

                Connection connection = null;
                PreparedStatement selectRetouch = null;
                ResultSet resultSet = null;

                public imaging() {
                    try {
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                        selectRetouch = connection.prepareStatement("select * from retouch limit 1 , ?");

                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                public ResultSet imaging_Result(String limitone) {
                    try {
                        selectRetouch.setString(1, limitone);
                        resultSet = selectRetouch.executeQuery();

                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return resultSet;
                }
            }
        %>
        <%
            String str = new String();
            str = request.getParameter("weeknum1");
            imaging image = new imaging();
            ResultSet images = image.imaging_Result(str);
        %>
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Retail_sku</td>
                    <td>Region</td>
                </tr>
                <% while (images.next()) {%>

                <tr>
                    <td><%= images.getString("retail_sku")%></td>
                    <td><%= images.getString("region")%></td>
                </tr>
                <% }%>
            </tbody>
        </table> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't post the complete exception stack trace. In which lines occurs the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @unwichtich updated in update1 section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try first by rearranging your imports and declarations followed by driver loading later on as a scriptlet :

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>
```

Next the class renaming is not okay. First letter of your class should be capital. So rename it to Imaging. It is better to define this class in your source package rather than declare inside JSP page and using it.

The problem area is your PreparedStatement:

```
selectRetouch.setString(1, limitone);
```

Since you are setting a limit value, the driver is expecting an Integer value and not a String. To get over this problem here is a workaround:

```
 selectRetouch.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(limitone));
```

To test this through URL you directly hit the link and pass the request parameter like this for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/yourappname/yourpage.jsp?weeknum1=12
```

Comment: Please check my answer, I added more.

Comment: I want to restrict the user to limit the rows.Yes it will work if i uncomment that lines. but i need to get input from user then i have to use it sql query .Updated my question (removed limt 1,10 and added 1, ? ) . Sorry about that .